# Open the web browser on Android emulator

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator

I just installed the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) on my Windows 7 64-bit. I'm creating a web app, so all I'd like to do is open the Android web browser. I double clicked on *tools/emulator.exe*, but all it did was flash a CMD box on the screen for a split second. I proceeded to read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html). It says I have to type this command in CMD to open the emulator:

```
emulator -avd <avd_name>
```

What exactly do I put in `<avd_name>` to open the web browser?

Comment: AVD is the name of your emulated device. It has nothing to do with what you're going to do with what you're going to do with the device. You can use ADB to run something on your device once the emulator has loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you must create an AVD (Android Virtual Device). How to do that, find out [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds). Afterwards, you can start it using the command you provided. When the emulator has started, you can simply click on web browser's icon to start it.

To create an AVD, I'd recommend using Eclipse and Android development tools for Eclipse; it's easier than using command line if you're just beginning Android development.

Comment: I created an AVD with a 128 MB SD card and the rest of the settings left as defaults. It took nearly 5 minutes to launch the AVD. Clicking around the interface feels sluggish. My computer is a Core i7 920 with 6 GB of DDR3 RAM. This should be more than enough to run a measly Android device. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

this has nothing to do with your app : you ave to create an AVD first, by using the AVD & SDK Manager, lauched by  android-sdk-dir\tools\android.bat

Answer (score 0):

AVD represents the name of the emulator and it has nothing to do with the application that you want to run, follow this procedure if you are using eclipse : go to run, select run configuration>>select your project>>go to target>> here you can select the specific android device according to your needs >> hit run.
i think that will solve your problem.